# Error: Undeclared namespace prefix x:

Tags: xml, soap, xml-namespaces

I am a SOAP newbie and struggling with how to resolve this error message,

> {:error, "500",      "Undeclared namespace prefix \"x\"\n at [row,col
>   {unknown-source}]: [1,168]"}

for the below SOAP envelope.  Because of terms and conditions of the host system I am trying to access, I have replaced identifying URL and credential info with "xxx" and removed the majority of objects.

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
            xmlns:read="urn://xxx/sdk/ReadObject" 
            xmlns:obj="http://xxx/object">
    <x:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                       xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>xxx</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">xxx</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </x:Header>
    <x:Body>
      <read:readEstimate>
        <read:estimate>
        <obj:id>38945</obj:id>
        </read:estimate>
      </read:readEstimate>
    </x:Body>
</x:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**To fix the problem of an undeclared namespace prefix (`x:`), do any *one* of the following:**

1. Replace `x:` with `soapenv:` in the SOAP envelope element names.
2. Change `xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"`
   to `xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"`.
3. Use a default namespace by changing `xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"`
   to `xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"` and removing `x:` in the SOAP envelope element names.

Comment: That did it!  Thanks for the 3 options as it helped me understand the xml  namespace prefix requirements.